# Is cookie part of the header of a http request/response? Is it a key value pair? How different is it than Accept or Content-type header keys?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, servlet-filters

What is the difference between an http header and a cookie? I'm learning Jsps and Servlets.
I am not understanding how a cookie is different than other header attributes..

For example: An http request would contain a list of header key-values. One of the header keys is a cookie. Just like `connection: Keep-Alive` or `accept-language: en-us`

Correct?

Comment: What didn't you understand in the answers to your previous question? A cookie is a concept. It is implemented as two headers: `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie`.

Comment: But thats just in java terms. JSP and Servlet terms. I'm trying to understand the cookie standard.. If there is one. What does a cookie contain. Any requirements? Format? How would some other webserver know which one is the cookie? I could have a multiple headers: `cookie: somecookie=value` and another `cookie-2: someString` and `CooKIe: somekey=SomeValue`..

Comment: @TazMan No, it isn't 'just in Java terms' or 'JSP and Servlet' terms either. It is in *HTTP* terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary purpose a cookie serves is to persist a small amount of state, remember that HTTP is stateless, in the browser without requiring that the data be re-added to every form request. For an explicit, real world example, consider why one would use [URL Rewriting](http://www.javatpoint.com/url-rewriting-in-session-tracking) instead of (or in addition) to a session tracking cookie.

Comment: Am I asking what a cookie is???

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I'm new to webdevelopment in general

Comment: Given two cookies "name" and "name2". The browser would send this header - "Cookie: name=value; name2=value2", The server would have originally sent (unless you're using javascript) "Set-Cookie: name=value
Set-Cookie: name2=value2; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT". You might want to try a logging proxy like fiddler (or firebug, or try f-12 in your browser) usually through the Browser Web-Developer Tools.

Comment: Does the server use the a response header NAMED "Set-Cookie": somename=somevalue; somename2=somevalue2.. And the request has a header NAMED cookie that it sends back to the server right?

Comment: Yes. Additionally, you could use a javascript method to add the cookie (instead of using the response header 'Set-Cookie').

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are like temporary storage of data on client side. browser put cookies in his temp directory and send these with each request .

But headers are hints to browser and server . to prepare himself . like `content type` header it tells that the request is sending data of that particular type like `application/json` will send json data now server will decide whether it can handle this(type)
    or not if it can not it will rise exception.

Comment: Why did you format this as code when it isn't?